# Resize/crop multiple files while preserving certain areas?

Tags: images, batch, gimp, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have 176 JPEG images that are `450x800` in size, and was wondering if there was a way to essentially resize them, but while preserving their content in certain areas (currently I'm only hoping for the middle).
Coincidentally, the size I wish to have is actually the reverse -- `800x450`.

I understand that a picture says a thousand words.

I have:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rYeJuIb.jpg]

Obviously what happens with an ordinary re-size:

[image]

I would like: [image]

Obviously, the white quadrilateral is something more complicated, but it's about the size, and it is white-on-black (I think it has a smooth transition towards black, so magic selection is out of the question.)

What helps immensely is that the background is exactly black everywhere, maybe it's possible to:

1. Select and crop a quadrilateral figure in the middle.
2. Make new or resize the background.
3. Paste cropped object.
4. Happiness!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you just wanting to crop the top, bottom, and sides? Or actually resize ?

Comment: See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Ahh, snap! It's possible to crop sides of the image too. Here's the command that worked for me: `convert *.jpg -bordercolor Black -border 175x0 -shave 0x150 <folder>`

Comment: @Wuuuf I think you can answer your own questions after a set time limit. You should post that as an answer for your question if it solved the issue.

Comment: @DarthAndroid Well, I granted the accepted answer to bodhi.zazen since it was their idea, and the fact that points matter more for them as I am a guest user :P

Comment: @Wuuuf You're just as much a user as any of the rest of us! :) Just hang around and ask good questions, and answer a few too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the most useful command line tool is convert, part of imagemagick

convert has many options , so much so that I can not recall all of them and have to look them up and then apply the options to the task at hand.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

In this case,

```
convert *.jpg -bordercolor Black -border 175x0 -shave 0x150 <folder>
```

worked for Wuuuf